# Could you move Thor's Hammer in a wheelbarrow?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, mjolnir

If Thor put his hammer down on a wheelbarrow you wouldn't be able to take it out of the wheelbarrow. However would you be able to wheel the wheelbarrow around?

Similarly if you can move the wheelbarrow, would the hammer fall out if you tipped the wheelbarrow?

Comment: There seems to be a marked difference between Thor putting his hammer down and Thor putting his hammer down **with the intent that it can't be moved afterwards**.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate, as this question specifies the MCU.

Comment: Also, within the MCU, we've seen that even a truck couldn't move Mjölnir. I agree with RIchard. It behaves however Thor wishes when he puts it down.

Answer (score 3):

The fact is that you should be "worthy" to being able to lift Mjölnir from his standing position.

This means that you cannot move it or lift it if you're not worthy, no matter wich tool or lever you use to try it. This is a magical attribute, so normal physics rules don't apply.

Could seem logical that, as you're not touching nor moving directly the hammer, you can tip the wheelbarrow or move it with Mjölnir inside. The fact is not, as you're not worthy, Mjölnir will refuse to get moved from the place he is, and thus, he will nail the wheelbarrow to the ground unless someone worthy tries to move it.

Comment: Some physics do apply, IronMan was able to carry Mjonir in space(0 Gravity) . I do agree with @Richard though.....and the line was "Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor"........I think you could carry it wheelbarrow or an elevator, plane, truck, car and even if you are able to lift it with some loop hole, if you are not worthy, it will just be a 42.3lbs hammer and nothing more.

Comment: In the Avengers movie he put it down on the helicarrier and it moved with the helicarrier. So that does not line up with this answer.

Comment: But under the will of Thor,

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on which description on Mjölnir you are taking in to consideration. The 1991 trading card for Thor's hammer states it weight is 42.3lbs and is made of Uru.

So if you can lift a wheel barrow that has 42.3lb on weight in it, you should be able to move a wheelbarrow with Mjölnir in it around.

If you tipped the wheelbarrow over, it would just fall to the floor.